# Using C++ with Google Maps API. Only text info required

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to call Google Maps API using a C++ code to retrieve text info about nearby locations.

I am trying to make a simple application (C++) which gives the information about Nearby places on entering longitude and latitude info. Only data I am looking for is the Name of Nearby place and its distance from mentioned location.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option would be to use the [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests) with the `JSON` format for request.

I don't know about any library that would perform the thing automatically, but there is a thread on StackOverflow about [JSON parsing in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245973/whats-the-best-c-json-parser) . Even it does not provide an answer it as good votes scores.

I guess the web call could be made with something like `curl`.

Comment: Any luck with my answer? or is it off-topic?

Comment: Yes. It was helpful. Finally I changed my plans of implementation. Using decarta's api for my application.